# is there a WPF version of FillRectangle

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to draw (via mouse drag) some rectangles onto a canvas.  Normally I'd use the Graphics class and FillRectangle on mousemove.

Does anyone have any good resources for doing this in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Rectangle` class. And set the Fill dependency property to the brush you want.

Here's a quick example in XAML

```
<Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="100" Width="200" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, basically it's best to put a Rect and RectangleGeometry into a Path, add the Path to the canvas and then change the Rect data on mousemove.

Something like that at least...